# How to update audit column automatically including navigational properties?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

There are plenty similar questions on SO about updating audit columns automatically, however they dont work for me because I also need to detect change of navigational properties.

At the moment I have a following code which I call on `SaveChanges()`:

```
private void UpdateAuditDateTimeValues()
{
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (var change in Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(
        x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        var entityWithDate = change.Entity as BaseModelWithDate;
        if (entityWithDate != null)
        {
            if (change.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entityWithDate.CreatedDate = currentDateTime;
            }
            entityWithDate.ModifiedDate = currentDateTime;
        }
    }
}
```

However the problem is that if I use an entity with Navigational properties like this:

```
public class Lineup : BaseModelWithDate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public string JerseyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

where Game and Player are different entites, this code doesnt work if I change Game or Player property.

It still works fine though if I modify JerseyNumber (string) property.

So the question is, how do you modify the code for `UpdateAuditDateTimeValues()` method so that it also detects entity state changes of navigational properties like Game or Player?

**Edit:**
This is how I assign properties in code:

```
lineupEntity.Game = this.Uow.GetRepository<Game>().FindSingleLocal(x => x.GameKey == _xmlNode.GameKey);
lineupEntity.Player = this.Uow.GetRepository<Player>().FindSingleLocal(x => x.PlayerId == _xmlNode.PlayerId);
lineupEntity.JerseyNumber = _xmlNode.JerseyNumber;
```

If `Game` changed but `Player` and `JerseyNumber` didnt, the change wont get detected.

Comment: Why not handle this in a database trigger? It's pretty useful to handle these auditing features entirely separately from the application level.

Comment: Have you tried setting the state on the navigation properties to modified, when you make changes to them? See this link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: Ideally this code should work, assuming `Game` and `Player` also inherit from `BaseModelWithDate`. Did you debug the code and see if any changes made to these properties is tracked?

Comment: @Luaan For a variety of reasons, really. At the moment I want to exhaust EF options first and if that doesnt work there is always going raw and hardcore option.

Comment: @Louis Not sure how to set Navigational properties to modified, however setting any entity state to modified explicitly forces EF to update the whole object even if actually only one field has been modified. NOt sure if that is what you meant. I am working in connected state btw

Comment: @aSharma It saves everything correctly, its just that the entity state remains Unchanged if I overwrite Game or Team property.

Comment: @Tanuki can you show the statements  where you set / overwrite Game or Team property.

Comment: @aSharma I've edited my answer to show statements

Comment: Is your method `FindSingleLocal` fetching the entities `AsNoTracking` by any chance.

Comment: No, it tries to find entity by looking at `DBSet.Local.FirstOrDefault` first, and if not found goes to `DBSet.FirstOrDefault` directly. Not sure if that is related to AsNoTracking or not.